# Blank Screen Edit Page when using Editor Role

Tags: user-roles, editor

When I’m using other user roles to either edit page,add new page or event post I’m getting a blank screen.

I thought it’s the W3 Total Cache doing this yet after I uninstalled it the problem still persist.

Is there a way to find out the problem?Every thing is normal when I'm using the admin role.

Comment: Sounds like either a plugin or your theme is messing about with user permissions and they're doing it wrong somewhere.  If you can access your PHP error logs there should be something in there to help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: It's all good now, I've increase my define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' ). It's kinda weird though. Since it's working fine in my admin.